# How to export results from R?

Tags: r

I am using the below function to run multiple regression models, need to understand how to export the results to a `.csv` file so that I can use it in my database.

```
Faltu %>% 
  group_by(subgroup) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(sales ~ month_year + weekday + sequence, .)))
```

Where Faltu is my data frame.

[image: Data in the image needs to be exported]

Comment: ``write.csv`` will work fine.

Comment: Choose an answer that best suits your questions by clicking the gray correct mark beside the answer you like you will see it will turn green.

Answer (score 2):

We could pipe `write.csv` at the end of your code:

Documentation of `write.csv` see here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AlphaPart/versions/0.8.1/topics/write.csv

```
# general:
write.csv(df,'Result.csv', row.names = FALSE)

# with your code:

Faltu %>% 
  group_by(subgroup) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(sales ~ month_year + weekday + sequence, .))) %>% 
  write.csv('Result.csv')
```

Output: file: `Result.csv` in your working directory:

```
"subgroup","term","estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value"
1,"Mens","Fixed","(Intercept)","0.849",0.302
2,"Mens","Fixed","month_year","0.0113",0.0226
3,"Mens","Fixed","weekday","0.449",0.0425
4,"Mens","Fixed","sequence","-0.000914",0.000322
5,"Mens","Pants","(Intercept)","0.474",4.63
6,"Mens","Pants","month_year","0.112",0.233
7,"Mens","Pants","weekday","0.387",0.362
8,"Mens","Pants","sequence","-0.204",0.342
9,"Mens","Pull","On","(Intercept)",0.271
10,"Mens","Pull","On","month_year",0.0514
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a very simple `copy and paste` method to copy results from `R` console and paste to `excel` file. It helps you to correctly copy your data frame to your computer `clipboard` such that you can past it to wherever you like. Follow this code:

```
write_excel <- function(x, row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE) {
  write.table(x, "clipboard", sep = "\t", row.names = row.names, col.names = col.names) # this is the function that do the `copy` margic.
}

library(magrittr)
Faltu %>% 
  group_by(subgroup) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(sales ~ month_year + weekday + sequence, .))) %>%
  write_excel() # This is the function call
```

with this go to the `excel` file your `data frame` to seat and do `Ctrl + C` on windows. or right-click and choose `paste`.

Watch the `video well demonstrated on YouTube` here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8vvw8V5aSc&t=143s  You will get the gist starting from `7:44` minutes of the video, please watch to the end.

Please `subscribe, like and ring the notification bell` to this channel

Answer (score 0):

I just copy results to the clipboard and paste on the Excel sheet. Then I use the splitting on the columns with the Excel Data -> Text to columns wizard. Then you can save the sheet as csv.